# How can I create a table with the filter option using the nicegui framework?

Tags: nicegui

I am trying to create a table having the filter option using any column value in nicegui
but unable to do so

I tried to document but It is not very clear to understand that, There are no examples on the internet as well. I am new to nicegui.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. But you can filter the rows of a `ui.table` like this:

```py
columns = [
    {'name': 'name', 'label': 'Name', 'field': 'name', 'required': True, 'align': 'left'},
    {'name': 'age', 'label': 'Age', 'field': 'age', 'sortable': True},
]
rows = [
    {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 18},
    {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 21},
    {'name': 'Carol'},
]
f = ui.input('Filter')
ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows, row_key='name').bind_filter_from(f, 'value')
```